# Sum of unique column combinions

Tags: r, aggregate, dplyr, summary

I am attempting to do two things to a dataset I currently have:

```
    ID    IV1 DV1 DV2 DV3 DV4 DV5 DV6 DV7
1  97330   3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
2 118619   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
3 101623   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4 202626   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 182925   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
6 179278   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

1. Find the unique number of column combinations of 7 binary
   independent variables (DV1 - DV7)
2. Find the sum of an independent count variable (IV1) by each unique group.

I have been able to determine the number of unique column combinations by using the following:

```
uniq <- unique(dat[,c('DV1','DV2','DV3','DV4','DV5','DV6','DV7')])
```

This indicates there are 101 unique combinations present in the dataset. What I *haven't* been able to figure out is how to determine how to sum the variable "IV1" by each unique group. I've been reading around on this site, and I'm fairly certain there is an easy dplyr answer to this, but it's eluded me so far.

NOTE: I'm essentially trying to find an R solution to perform a "conjunctive analysis" which is displayed in [this paper](http://engagedscholarship.csuohio.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1041&context=clsoc_crim_facpub). There is sample code for SPSS, SAS and STATA at the end of the paper.

Comment: For #1 with dplyr: `dat %>% select(DV1:DV7) %>% distinct %>% nrow`. This command should work for the whole thing `dat %>% group_by(DV1:DV7) %>% summarise(tot_IV1 = sum(IV1))` but it looks like they haven't coded `group_by` for that use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(dat, DV1, DV2, DV3, DV4, DV5, DV6, DV7) %>%
    summarize(sumIV1 = sum(IV1))
```

The number of rows in the result is the number of unique combinations present in your data. The `sumIV1` column, of course, has the group-wise sum of `IV1`.

Thanks to Frank in the comments, we can use strings with `group_by_` to simplify:

```
group_by_(dat, .dots = paste0("DV", 1:7)) %>%
         summarize(sumIV1 = sum(IV1))
```

Comment: Indeed, this produces the desired result. I wasn't aware the solution was so simple using "group_by." Many thanks!

Comment: @DavidArenburg surely it is, but as per Frank's comment "This command should work... but it looks like they haven't coded `group_by` for that use-case."

Comment: Ah, that's how you do it! I always forget that I need to name `.dots` to get that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(X = c(1, 1, 1 , 1), Y = c(2, 2 , 3 , 4), Z = c(1,1,3,1))
```

Where X, Y ... are your columns.

Then use the `Reduce` function:

`DT[,  join_grp := Reduce(paste,list(X,Y,Z))]`

This gives:

```
DT
   X Y Z join_grp
1: 1 2 1    1 2 1
2: 1 2 1    1 2 1
3: 1 3 3    1 3 3
4: 1 4 1    1 4 1
```

And we can find:

```
unique(DT[, join_grp])
[1] "1 2 1" "1 3 3" "1 4 1"
```

For the sums:

```
DT[ , sum(X), by = join_grp]
```

Just put whatever column you want to sum in place of the `X`

**Concise Solution**

`DT[,  join_grp := Reduce(paste,list(X,Y,Z))][ , sum(X), by = join_grp]`

or

`DT[ , sum(X), by = list(Reduce(paste,list(X,Y,Z)))]`

Comment: The OP's example is also reproducible with very little work.

Comment: I think a concise solution will be just `DT[ , .N, by = .(X, Y, Z)]`, no?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think OP needs `sum(X)`, not `.N`. For whatever reason, I don't get the right sum when I run that `DT[ , sum(X), by = .(X, Y, Z)]` though

Comment: Because you both summing `X` and grouping by `X`. OP is summing a column which isn't being grouped by. I would solve this using `setDT(dat)[, sum(IV1), by = c(tail(names(dat), -2L))]` on OPs original data set.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Interesting... Makes sense why that is the case, but would prefer to use your method to sum even if the column was part of the group

Comment: If the column is part of the group it appears only once, this is why your are getting a single value.

Comment: @Gregor I don't think that that is what happens. Test with `DT[ , sum(X), by = .(X, Y, Z)]`. You get `1` as the sum for `1 2 1`, even when it occurs twice.

Comment: Why do insist on this specific case? This isn't what the OP is dealing with.